# matrix inside matrix when multiplying symbolic matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab, i'm trying to multiply symbolic matrices(size 3X3). The output shows matrix having some elements which are themselves matrices.
why some of the elements are matrices?

Example code:

```
syms a1 a2 a3
F2 = [a1+0.0003 .0002 .0004; a2+.0003 .0005 .0003; a3+.0003 .0002 .0004];
C2 = F2'*F2;
K = C2^(16/57); 
T = inv(K)*C2*inv(K);
S = T - 0.5*T^2 + 0.33*T^3;
```

Comment: In what programming language/environment this happens?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, I'm using Matlab

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: a1 a2 a3 are symbolic variables.  F2=[a1+0.0003 .0002 .0004; a2+.0003 .0005 .0003; a3+.0003 .0002 .0004]; C2=F2'*F2; K=C2^(16/57); T= inv(K)*C2*inv(K); S=T-0.5*T^2+0.33*T^3;  S contains elements which are themselves matrices

Comment: If I run the provided code, `S` is a 3x3 matrix, where each element is a 1x1 `sym`. What results do you get in that case?

Comment: if u see the denominator of the first element in S, it starts with matrix[.........          doesnt that mean it is a matrix??

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `K = C2^(16/57)`. Taking the root of a matrix is not trivial and solutions don't always exist. That's why MATLAB cannot resolve this expression. Try for example:

```
A = syms('A',[3,3]);    % create 3x3 symbolic matrix
B = A^(1/3);            % calculate the 3rd root of A
```

The result will be

```
ans = matrix([[a1_1, a1_2, a1_3], [a2_1, a2_2, a2_3], [a3_1, a3_2, a3_3]])^(1/3)
```

The same happens in your case. If you look closely, you will see that the `matrix` expression in `S(1,1)` is of the form `matrix(...)^(32/57)`

Comment: thanks !!! is there any way to get around this difficulty? i need to really use this expression in the code and obtain a solution. approx solution perhaps.

Comment: Does your result have to be symbolic, or will you insert values for  `a1`,`a2`,`a3` at some point and evaluate `S` for these?